# NextJS - breadcrumbs click changes url but not page content

Tags: reactjs, next.js, url-routing, breadcrumbs

I have a nextjs site - in the admin section I have some fairly standard breadcrumbs.

I have this breadcrumbs function:

```
export function Breadcrumbs({ list }) {
  return (
    <div className="text-sm breadcrumbs">
      <ul>
        {list.map((row,idx) => (
          <li key={`breadcrumb${row.href??idx}`}>
            {row.href ? (
              <Link href={row.href} passHref>
                <a>{row.label}</a>
              </Link>
            ) : (
              <a>{row.label}</a>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

which outputs this

```
<div class="text-sm breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/admin/companies">Companies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/company/2583wa4kovh">Beach Resort</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/company/2583wa4kovh/listing/1t9sfhpab4m">Beach Resort</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Example links are

- /admin/company/2583wa4kovh/listing/1t9sfhpab4m
- /admin/company/2583wa4kovh

When I am on the listing page and click the shorter link the URL changes but the page content doesn't. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a folder structure, please?

Comment: sure @Morani

admin/[companyid]/index.js

admin/[companyid]/listing/[listingid]/index.js

admin/[companyid]/billing/index.js

etc